# In woocommerce who is responsible for sending the receipt email?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I'm writing a Paypal Pro woo commerce extension to allow it to accept credit card directly on my websites. When I test things, everything works well. The only thing that I don't get is an email notification.

So I would like to know does my gatway class need to send the receipt email or the internals of the WooCommerece should take care of that for successful order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce sends the emails - triggered by the payment_complete method of the order class.

By the way, WC has an official paypal pro extension: http://www.woothemes.com/extension/paypal-pro/ written by myself.